# Add newline between characters in every line in list of strings c#

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list of strings containing an arbitrary number of lines. Each line is 12 characters long, and I want to print its content to a text-file. This is fairly easy doing

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@".\strings.txt", myList);
```

Now, I want to insert a `newLine` after every 6 characters, effectively doubling the count number of the list.

E.g

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@".\strings.txt", myList);
// Output from strings.txt
123456789ABC
123456789ABC 
// ...

// command to insert newLine after every 6 characters in myList
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@".\strings.txt", myListWithNewLines);
// Output from strings.txt
123456
789ABC
123456
789ABC
```

Comment: You might be interested in [`String.Insert(int startIndex, string value)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx)

Comment: Please downvoters, add a reason for the downvote and I will try to improve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@".\strings.txt", myList.Select(x => x.Length > 6 ? x.Insert(6, Environment.NewLine) : x));
```

Or, if you *know* every line *really* has 12 characters:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@".\strings.txt", myList.Select(x => x.Insert(6, Environment.NewLine)));
```

Comment: Thanks man. How does the `x=>...` works? Either way, it solved my problem

Comment: Also, how can I store this in a new list instead of writing it to file? Thank you very much sir! EDIT: Figured out, appended `ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

With your set, you can make some nice assumptions and print substrings. Consider the following example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StringSplit
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = @"123456789ABC
123456789ABC";

            string[] lines = input.Split(new char[]{'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var l in lines)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(l.Substring(0, 6));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(l.Substring(6, 6));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
123456
789ABC
123456
789ABC
```